# pipenv jupyter notebook matplotlib moviepy TypeError

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, moviepy

I installed jupyter notebook matplotlib and moviepy to my pipenv environment. When I run this code sample from  https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/working_with_matplotlib.html

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from moviepy.editor import VideoClip
from moviepy.video.io.bindings import mplfig_to_npimage

x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 200)

duration = 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
def make_frame(t):
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(x, np.sinc(x**2) + np.sin(x + 2*np.pi/duration * t), lw=3)
    ax.set_ylim(-1.5, 2.5)
    return mplfig_to_npimage(fig)

animation = VideoClip(make_frame, duration=duration)
animation.ipython_display(fps=20, loop=True, autoplay=True)
```

I get this TypeError:

```
~/.local/share/virtualenvs/Fourier_Analyses-WlUtXrFk/lib/python3.9/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py in convert_masks_to_RGB(f, clip, *a, **k)
     20     if clip.ismask:
     21         clip = clip.to_RGB()
---> 22     return f(clip, *a, **k)
     23 
     24 @decorator.decorator

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/Fourier_Analyses-WlUtXrFk/lib/python3.9/site-packages/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py in write_videofile(self, filename, fps, codec, bitrate, audio, audio_fps, preset, audio_nbytes, audio_codec, audio_bitrate, audio_bufsize, temp_audiofile, rewrite_audio, remove_temp, write_logfile, verbose, threads, ffmpeg_params, logger)
    298                                        logger=logger)
    299 
--> 300         ffmpeg_write_video(self, filename, fps, codec,
    301                            bitrate=bitrate,
    302                            preset=preset,

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/Fourier_Analyses-WlUtXrFk/lib/python3.9/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_writer.py in ffmpeg_write_video(clip, filename, fps, codec, bitrate, preset, withmask, write_logfile, audiofile, verbose, threads, ffmpeg_params, logger)
    211         logfile = None
    212     logger(message='Moviepy - Writing video %s\n' % filename)
--> 213     with FFMPEG_VideoWriter(filename, clip.size, fps, codec = codec,
    214                                 preset=preset, bitrate=bitrate, logfile=logfile,
    215                                 audiofile=audiofile, threads=threads,

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/Fourier_Analyses-WlUtXrFk/lib/python3.9/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_writer.py in __init__(self, filename, size, fps, codec, audiofile, preset, bitrate, withmask, logfile, threads, ffmpeg_params)
     86             '-s', '%dx%d' % (size[0], size[1]),
     87             '-pix_fmt', 'rgba' if withmask else 'rgb24',
---> 88             '-r', '%.02f' % fps,
     89             '-an', '-i', '-'
     90         ]

TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType
```

It seems to be related to ffmpeg. I have ffmpeg installed on my system. Does anybody have an idea what is wrong?

Comment: having the same issue. were you ever able to solve this?